# I can't set text of JLabel from another class

Tags: java, swing

I have a JLabel that I need to setText it from another class. Let's just call this JLabel soupLabel.

The soupLabel is in a JPanel class (class extends JPanel), called SoupPage. SoupPage is actually a card of a mainGUI class.

I have another class called Confirmation Class (class extends JFrame). This class is a pop up after pressing a button from Soup Class.

I tried to set text soupLabel (which is in Soup Class) from Confirmation Class but to no avail.

MainGUI

```
public class mainGUI extends JFrame{
    private CardLayout card;

    public mainGUI(){
       card = new CardLayout();
       setLayout(card);
    }

    private void createSoupPage(){
    SoupPage sp = new SoupPage(this);
    add(sp, "Soup Page");
    }
}
```

EDITED: SoupPage with Confirmation pop up

```
public class SoupPage extends JPanel{
    mainGUI gui;
    public JLabel soupLabel;
    public JButton cfmBtn;

    public SoupPage(mainGUI gui){
        this.gui = gui;

        soupLabel = new JLabel("blabla");

        cfmBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Confirmation cfmPopUp = new Confirmation();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Confirmation

```
public class Confirmation extends JDialog{
    JButton clrBtn;

    public Confirmation(){
         SoupPage sp = new SoupPage();

         clrBtn = new JButton("Clear");
         clrBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            sp.soupLabel.setText("some other text bla bla");
            }
         });
    }
}
```

This is the part where it doesn't work.

Comment: In your example, the text is already `"blabla"` and pressing the button sets that to `"blabla"` again. What effect do you expect?

Comment: Hmm my bad. It's not bla bla. I'm just trying to set to another text.

Comment: But you work with a different SoupPage every time how you think this affect all the other instances?

Comment: How do I pass down that instance from the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work. This is because you are trying to set the text of soupLabel of a different SoupPage object which is never added to mainGUI. What you need to do is to set the text of the souplabel of SoupPage class instance declared in your mainGUI class.What you should do ??
1. Tou should never use JFrame for popup. Change that to JDialog. It looks really odd when two icons appear in taskbar and also there may be problem of focus. 
2. Now next to solve your actual problem declare a SoupPage instance outside your private method in mainGUI. Then redefine your Confirmation class like this

```
  public class Confirmation extends JDialog{
    JButton clrBtn;

    public Confirmation(SoupPage sp){

         clrBtn = new JButton("Clear");
         clrBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            sp.soupLabel.setText("some other text bla bla");
            }
         });
    }
}
```

Now while calling Confirmation from mainGUi just pass the instance declared there.
**UPDATE**

Try this code where I have modified all the three classes and tested which will work perfectly according to your needs

```
class mainGUI extends JFrame{
    private CardLayout card;
    private SoupPage sp;

    mainGUI(){
       card = new CardLayout();
       setLayout(card);
    }

    private void createSoupPage(){
      sp = new SoupPage(this);
      add(sp,"Soup Page");
    }

    public void setSoupPageText(String text){
      sp.soupLabel.setText(text);
    }


}

class SoupPage extends JPanel{
    mainGUI gui;
    JLabel soupLabel;
    JButton cfmBtn;

    SoupPage(mainGUI gui){
        this.gui = gui;

        soupLabel = new JLabel("blabla");

        cfmBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Confirmation cfmPopUp = new Confirmation(gui);
            }
        });
    }
}



class Confirmation extends JDialog{
    JButton clrBtn;

    Confirmation(mainGUI gui){

         clrBtn = new JButton("Clear");
         clrBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            gui.setSoupPageText("some other text bla bla");
            }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. Eclipse required me to put a final modifier at the front of the instance though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are setting the action listener on a new SoupPage instance that you haven't added to mainGUI. You have to pass the SoupPage instance that mainGUI creates into the constructor of Confirmation:

```
public Confirmation(SoupPage sp){
     clrBtn = new JButton("Clear");
     clrBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        sp.soupLabel.setText("some other text bla bla");
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Actually I've tried that. The problem now is I got an error when trying to create the pop up

Comment: You need to pass the SoupPage instance into the constructor: new Confirmation(sp);

Comment: It's a matter of structuring your program such that you're able to do that.

Comment: Confirmation popUp = new Confirmation() is in SoupPage class.

Comment: Confirmation popUp = new Confirmation(this);
Tried that didn't work either -.-"